# Error: Route.post() requires a callback function

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

```
C:\Users\I ..\OneDrive\ecom-sql\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:202
        throw new Error(msg);
        ^

Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
    at Route.<computed> [as post] (C:\Users\I Am Moooooti\OneDrive\ecom-sql\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:202:15)
    at Function.app.<computed> [as post] (C:\Users\I .. \OneDrive\ecom-sql\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:482:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\I Am Moooooti\OneDrive\ecom-sql\index.js:53:5)
.......... so on
```

**index.js file**

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const db = require("./models/main");
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const session = require('express-session')
const passport = require('passport')
const { register, login } = require("./handlers/user.handler")
const app = express();

var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:8080"
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const sessionConfig = {
  name: 'session',
  secret: '25658595',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: true,
    expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
  },
};

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(session(sessionConfig));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Routes for authentication
app.post('/register', register);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

**user.handler.js File**

```
const db = require("../models/main");
const user = db.users;
const Op = db.Sequelize.Op;

exports.register = (req, res) => {
    res.json({ 'success': 'Successfully registered!' })
}
```

*I had changed a bit of code but i have not chaned anything in my inde.js file after i run my project it was showing me this error i dont know where i am doing wrong i have tried everything. Please help me :)*

Answer (score -1):

**Syntax problem**

*I Have to write this*

```
app.post("/register", register);
```

*instead of this*

```
app.post('/register', register);
```

Comment: this is not logical at all :/ actually in javascript but other languages may complain about using double quote instead of single quote

Comment: What are you trying to say I did not understand

Comment: Check [this link](https://flexiple.com/double-vs-single-quotes-javascript/) out, you will get the point

Comment: this was the problem when i add the double quotes the error was gone

Comment: Maybe that error was the `ESLINT` balming about your code style it should not be a logical error from the javascript engine

Comment: Maybe that was a ESLINT error. BY the way thanks for your coments

Comment: You are welcome I gave that a try and see that was an `ESLINT` error for sure ;)